# numpy `diagflat` for specified axis

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I want to expand the axis of a `ndarray` to a diagonal matrix in the fashion of `diagflat`

E.g.

```
In [ ]: import numpy as np

In [ ]: example = np.random.random((200, 5))
In [ ]: example.shape
Out[ ]: (200, 5)
```

What I am looking for, is something like:

```
In [ ]: np.diagflat(example, axis=-1).shape
Out[ ]: (200, 5, 5)
```

`diagflat` has however `axis` argument. My idea was the to simply insert a new axis in for example and multiply it with a unit matrix.

```
In [ ]: Id = np.eye(example.shape[-1])
In [ ]: (example[..., np.newaxis] @ Id).shape
ValueError: shapes (200,5,1) and (5,5) not aligned: 1 (dim 2) != 5 (dim 0)
```

This raises however an error, apparently broadcasting is not applied for matrix multiplications. Is there an elegant solution, or do I have to create and fill the array by hand?

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you mean by "diagflat has however no such argument.". Please explain in the interest of readers who might help you

Comment: Simply do : `example[..., np.newaxis] * Id`.

Comment: @Divakar thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. I feel a bit stupid about not remembering how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```
example[..., np.newaxis] * Id
```